# Telerik MVC Extensions GridBindingToData sample: CRUD operations using ADO.NET DataTable (arbitrary table)?

Tags: sql-server-2005, model-view-controller, ado.net, datatable, telerik

In GridBindingToDataTableSample sample that can be found at this URL:
http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/crud-operations-using-ado-net-datatable.aspx
they hard coded dataKeys and columns collection.
I need a generic CRUD code that would work with Html.Telerik().Grid HTML helper.

Imagine that I will have some metadata TableColumnMedatata table that will contain Table/Column metadata:

```
table    column        type     length    pk
=============================================
EmpLoc   EmployeeID    int      4         1
EmpLoc   LocID         int      4         1
---------------------------------------------
Orders   OrderID       int      4         1
Orders   CustomerID    nchar    10        0
Orders   EmployeeID    int      4         0
Orders   OrderDate     datetime 8         0
Orders   ShipVia       int      4         0 
Orders   Freight       money    8         0
Orders   ShipName      nvarchar 80        0
---------------------------------------------
Employees EmployeeID   int      4         1
Employees LastName     nvarchar 40        0
Employees FirstName    nvarchar 20        0
```

I need some suggestions on how to modify index.aspx to enable universal form to work against any DataTable retrieved from SQL Server.

Thanks,
Rad

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the table columns and create grid columns on the fly.

Comment: Thanks Atanask. Do you mean I need to use: Html.Telerik().Grid(Model).Name("Grid").Columns(columns => columns.LoadSettings((IEnumerable<GridColumnSettings>)ViewData["Columns"])). Do you have an examply of how you would handle universal CRUD for any table? Thanks ,Rad

Comment: We don't have such an example. Frankly I don't think universal editing to any DataTable can be achieved easily. You need to specify the data keys at least which I am not sure how to do for every DataTable.